# How can I go onto a new line whilst staying on the same level of list in markdown?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, markdown, readme

I'm trying to write a readme file for my project. The project simulates multiple systems of chemical reactions in parallel and sequentially.

I'm trying to write a list of each system of chemical equations, with one system occupying one level of the markdown list. Only some of the systems of chemical equations have multiple reactions I want each reaction to be on a different line but still occupy the same level of the list.

[image]

The attached picture shows what I'm trying to achieve on the left and how it actually appears on the markdown preview is on the right.

Any suggestions?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! removed the `` so its no longer a code snippet and used the .